# What are the drawbacks of utilizing sample weights in classification tasks?

Tags: classification, class-imbalance

In classification tasks, especially when dealing with unbalanced data, using sample weights can be beneficial. However, it's not always the default choice in ML libraries like [AutoGluon TabularPredictor](https://auto.gluon.ai/scoredebugweight/api/autogluon.predictor.html) and [LightGBM LGBMClassifier](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html).

Why? Are there drawbacks to always using sample weights? When might it not be advisable to employ them?